# PDF Reader scrolling in full screen mode

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

There is a `View` - `Page Display` - `Enable Scrolling` option in Adobe PDF Reader 11. This seems to be disabled when in full screen mode. How to enable the above scrolling feature when in full screen mode? The only one that seems to work there is the single page display option.

Comment: Consider changing the accepted answer to @Tsagana‘s. It works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've googled [this](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/846103):

> Go into fullscreen : Ctrl + L
>
> Enable Autoscroll : Ctrl + Shift + H
>
> Disable Autoscroll : Ctrl + Shift + H
>
> And Voila ... Continous scrolling with arrow keys on fullscreen mode

Unfortunately, I didn't check it in your version of Adobe PDF reader but works in mine Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 2017.012.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go into full-screen : Ctrl + L

Fit in windows and enable scrolling: Ctrl + H

Answer (score 0):

Try Shift + H for normal scrolling.

Cheers.

Comment: This doesn't work in full-screen

Answer (score -2):

Full screen and scrolling contradict each other. Full screen means that the whole page is visible on screen (and nothing else).

You may look at the various display settings, in particular hiding toolbars, menu items and other controls, and that should still allow for scrolling.